# Prove $A=\{f_n(x)\in C_{[a,b]}:f_n(x)=x^n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Prove $A=\{f_n(x)\in C_{[0,1]}:f_n(x)=x^n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is not a compact set.

I try to prove A is not closed, in particular.

Let $(g_n)_n \in A$ such that $g_n \rightarrow g_0$  and show $g_n$ is not convergent in $C_{[0,1]}$. So A is not closed.

But I feel this proof is not very reasonable. So I want to try to prove that the set of adherent points is empty, then A is a closed set. But I don't know how I should prove it that way.

Comment: Do you mean $f_n\in C_{[a, b]}$?

Comment: Presumably your are considering the uniform norm on $\mathcal{C}([0,1]$  Notice that no subsequence of $A$ converges (uniformly). (Every subsequuence converges pointwise to the function $1-\mathbb{1}_{[0,1)}=\mathbb{1}_{\{1\}}$ which is neither an element of $A$ nor continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Recall Ascoli-Arzelà theorem:
Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be compact and let $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathrm{C}^{0}(K) .$ Then $\mathcal{F}$ is compact in $\left(\mathbf{C}^{0}(K),\|\cdot\|_{\infty}\right)$ if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ is closed in $\left(\mathbf{C}^{0}(K),\|\cdot\|_{\infty}\right)$, bounded in $\left(\mathbf{C}^{0}(K),\|\cdot\|_{\infty}\right)$, equicontinuous.

Hint: what about the equicontinuity of the functions in your set?